# cant print the php variable on other page using ajax POST

Tags: php, ajax

I am back to development and need some help or tip.

I want to POST a variable using AJAX on another page but it is not working. My post variable is empty.

my code is (simplified version)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
    function logWriter(x){
    var str;
   switch(x) {
   case "A": 
      str = "hello1";
       break;
   case "B": 
       str = "hello2";
       break;
   default: 
       //default
   }
   
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'm.php',
      data: { 'field1': str },
   });
};
</script>

<div>
    <a href="m.php" onclick = "logWriter('A');">Link 1</a>
    <a href="m.php" onclick = "logWriter('B');">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

the code for m.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']))
echo $_POST['field1'];
?>
```

I already searched for this problem over StackOverflow but no success :(

[How to pass parameters in $ajax POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697034/how-to-pass-parameters-in-ajax-post)

[Can't print POST variable from AJAX using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532889/cant-print-post-variable-from-ajax-using-php)

can anyone guide me in right direction. Thank you

Comment: use  console.log()   and inside put the get from action  $.ajax({ ... post  ..  and use  post requests with  'm.php?'+Date.now()  to archieve  different calls and so avoid  cache errors

Comment: follow up I tried to check with Chrome Developer tools --> network fetch/XHR

my variable value is coming from Ajax on another page but it is not showing on the page

Comment: follow up i tried to take the varibale in session and it is working

Comment: so somehow the variable is reseating the value on page load

Comment: which i need to figure it out

Comment: "*my variable value is coming from Ajax on another page*" - does it mean you see the response from PHP in devtools? "*it is not showing on the page*" - it won't show up on the page until you add some JS which adds it *on* the page ...?

Comment: Are you asking how to update the page with the AJAX response?

Comment: console.log using is meant to run in browser press ctrl+shift+K when you open a new tab then run your script to see the results or refresh F5 key to see results again

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want to do following

I have a main page JKL.php
on the main page i have a link in A HREF tag which is leading to page ABC.php
i want to take some value from main page (JKL.php) to a third page which is XYZ.php **when the user is clicking on the link which is in HREF tag**
in short two events are happening 
1. user is going to ABC.php page 
2. Ajax is sending the value to XYZ.php

i think my problem is these two event occurance which is reseting the value of my post variable but I am not sure

Comment: Where is the 3rd page in your code above?  I suggest editing your question, and trying to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the problem.  Currently it is not clear what you are trying to do, nor what the problem is.